# Show/Hide <div> section when drop down selection is made

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I have a drop down list and when something is selected from it, certain div's need to hide or show. I have this working for another drop down that basically controls the entire view of the page, but I can't get this drop to work and the code is almost identical. I have tried many different things.

Here is the JQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#ChangeRequestType").focus();


    $("#ChangeRequestType").change(changeRequestDisplay);


    changeRequestDisplay();

});
```

More Code for it:

```
function changeRequestDisplay() {

    var action = $("#ChangeRequestType").val();

    if (action == "N/A") {
        DisplayOnlyDefaultChangeMenu();

    }
    else if (action == "Description") {
        DisplayDescriptionChange();

    }
    else if (action == "Procurement Category") {
        DisplayProcurementCategoryChange();

    }
    else if (action == "NonStandard Conversions") {
        DisplayNonStandardChangeRequest();

    }
    else if (action == "Item Group") {
        DisplayItemGroupChange();

    }
    else if (action == "Extended Description") {
        DisplayExtDescriptionChange();

    }
    else if (action == "More") {
        DisplayMultipleChange();
    }

}
```

More Code for it:

```
 function DisplayOnlyDefaultChangeMenu() {

    $("tr").show();
    $("#salesSetups").hide("slow");
    $("#requiredInfo").show("slow");
    $("#purchaseBUTable").show("slow");
    $("#fullAndBasicSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#fullAndSalesSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#salesProcurementExtras").hide("slow");

    $("#changeRequests").show("slow");
    $("#ExtDescriptionRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#ItemGroupChange").hide("slow");

    $("#DescriptionRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#ProcurementCategoryRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#NonStandardConversionRequest").hide("slow");

}
function DisplayExtDescriptionChange() {

    $("tr").show();
    $("#salesSetups").hide("slow");
    $("#requiredInfo").show("slow");
    $("#purchaseBUTable").show("slow");
    $("#fullAndBasicSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#fullAndSalesSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#salesProcurementExtras").hide("slow");

    $("#changeRequests").show("slow");
    $("#ExtDescriptionRequest").show("slow");
    $("#ItemGroupChange").hide("slow");

    $("#DescriptionRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#ProcurementCategoryRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#NonStandardConversionRequest").hide("slow");

}


function DisplayDescriptionChange() {

    $("tr").show();
    $("#salesSetups").hide("slow");
    $("#requiredInfo").show("slow");
    $("#purchaseBUTable").show("slow");
    $("#fullAndBasicSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#fullAndSalesSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#salesProcurementExtras").hide("slow");

    $("#changeRequests").show("slow");
    $("#DescriptionRequest").show("slow");
    $("#ProcurementCategoryRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#NonStandardConversionRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#ExtDescriptionRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#ItemGroupChange").hide("slow");
}
function DisplayProcurementCategoryChange() {

    $("tr").show();
    $("#salesSetups").hide("slow");
    $("#requiredInfo").show("slow");
    $("#purchaseBUTable").show("slow");
    $("#fullAndBasicSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#fullAndSalesSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#salesProcurementExtras").hide("slow");

    $("#changeRequests").show("slow");
    $("#DescriptionRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#ProcurementCategoryRequest").show("slow");
    $("#NonStandardConversionRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#ExtDescriptionRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#ItemGroupChange").hide("slow");
}
function DisplayNonStandardChangeRequest() {

    $("tr").show();
    $("#salesSetups").hide("slow");
    $("#requiredInfo").show("slow");
    $("#purchaseBUTable").show("slow");
    $("#fullAndBasicSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#fullAndSalesSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#salesProcurementExtras").hide("slow");

    $("#changeRequests").show("slow");
    $("#DescriptionRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#ProcurementCategoryRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#NonStandardConversionRequest").show("slow");
    $("#ExtDescriptionRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#ItemGroupChange").hide("slow");
}
function DisplayItemGroupChange() {

    $("tr").show();
    $("#salesSetups").hide("slow");
    $("#requiredInfo").show("slow");
    $("#purchaseBUTable").show("slow");
    $("#fullAndBasicSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#fullAndSalesSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#salesProcurementExtras").hide("slow");

    $("#changeRequests").show("slow");
    $("#DescriptionRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#ProcurementCategoryRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#NonStandardConversionRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#ExtDescriptionRequest").hide("slow");
    $("#ItemGroupChange").show("slow");
}
function DisplayMultipleChange() {

    $("tr").show();
    $("#salesSetups").hide("slow");
    $("#requiredInfo").show("slow");
    $("#purchaseBUTable").show("slow");
    $("#fullAndBasicSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#fullAndSalesSetup").hide("slow");
    $("#salesProcurementExtras").hide("slow");

    $("#changeRequests").show("slow");
    $("#DescriptionRequest").show("slow");
    $("#ProcurementCategoryRequest").show("slow");
    $("#NonStandardConversionRequest").show("slow");
    $("#ExtDescriptionRequest").show("slow");
    $("#ItemGroupChange").show("slow");
}
```

Here is where I try and implement it all

```
<div class="span-18 last" id="changeRequests">
  <table class="item-display">
    <tr>
      <td class="label required">Change Request Type</td>
      <td class="value" colspan="5">
        @Html.DropDownList("ChangeRequestType", new List<SelectListItem>
          {
            new SelectListItem { Text ="Select Option", Value="N/A"},
            new SelectListItem { Text ="Item Group", Value="Item Group" },
            new SelectListItem { Text ="Description", Value="Description" },
            new SelectListItem { Text ="Extended Description", Value="Extended Description" },
            new SelectListItem { Text ="Procurement Category", Value="Procurement Category" },
            new SelectListItem { Text ="NonStandard Conversion", Value="NonStandard Conversions" },
            new SelectListItem { Text ="More Than One Change Type", Value="More" },

          }, new { onchange = "changeRequestDisplay()"})
      </td>
    </tr>
```

I have double and triple checked the `<div>` id's for the sections and the values for the drop down selection like 100000 times and there doesn't seem to be a problem so I can not seem to pinpoint the issue as to why they all remain hidden no matter what is selected.

Comment: try `===` in your conditional statements

Comment: That didn't affect it any, everything still remains hidden

Comment: just reassuring, but you did debug are receiving the values that you are expecting?

Comment: this is mt first time working with this stuff, Im using Visual Studios 2012, how do I view the values as its debugging?\

Comment: well technically you don't have to debug to see the value.. you could just set an alert like so:  `var action = $("#ChangeRequestType").val(); alert(action);`

Comment: Ok, so it shows something like local host:1234 says:                            (but there is nothing there) so im assuming that measn its not grabbing the values?

Comment: what about trying `var action = $('#ChangeRequestType').options[this.selectedIndex].label;`

Comment: how are you expecting a value from a dropdownlist when your `id` that is `ChangeRequestType` isn't on the correct element?  shouldn't `id = ChangeRequestType` be on the 2nd `td` element, where your dropdownlist is?

Comment: fixed the issue, i just took the id off the <td> comlpetely so now the only Id is ont the html dropdownlist helper

Comment: good, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Well to get the selected value, you should use

```
$("#ChangeRequestType option:selected").val();
```

It will surely solve your problem

Comment: your `action` variable do not have the selected value

Answer (score -1):

This line is the problem:

`$("tr").show();`

Try `$("#ChangeRequestType").closest("tr")`

Comment: this shouldnt be the issue as it works for a different drop down selection in the program, changing it to that didn't help it either but thank you